# Disregard right click and make it shift click instead

Tags: java, sikuli

Is it possible to (in sikuli/java) to make a right click event form a shift click and disregard what would normally happen with the right click?

Thanks,

Odin

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a Sikuli wrapper that would "overwrite" the right click method. If you would then use your wrapper, all your scripts would do shift click instead of right click.

sikuliwrapper.py

```
...
from sikuli.Sikuli import Region as SikuliRegion
...

class Region(SikuliRegion, BaseLogger):

    def rightClick(self, target, modifiers=0):
        try:
            keyDown(Key.SHIFT)
            SikuliRegion.click(self, target, modifiers)
            KeyUp(Key.SHIFT)
        except FindFailed, e:   
            raise e
```

So whenever you will have for example

```
myreg = Region(0,0,300,300)
myreg.rightClick("pattern.png")
```

you will actually perform a Shift Click on the image.

Hope I understood what you wanted correctly.
More info on how to write a wrapper for sikuli here:
http://blog.mykhailo.com/2011/02/how-to-sikuli-and-robot-framework.html#step3